# How to set AuthnContext in Azure AD B2C IDP Saml response

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am involved in a project to build a new Azure AD B2C IDP and need to support some legacy Saml2 SPs.  These login requests include a RequestedAuthnContext element and require *PasswordProtectedTransport*, however the Saml response from B2C has an AuthnContextClassRef of *unspecified* in the assertion and therefore is being rejected by the SP.  So far I have been unable to find any information on how to set this from within a custom policy.  Is anyone able to confirm whether or not this is actually possible and if so what is involved?

Comment: Please refer this link for more details : - http://shibboleth.net/pipermail/users/2012-January/002591.html

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, you can configure the ‘AuthContext.xml’ or the ‘LoginHandler.xml’ file for the SAML response on the IdP side (Azure AD B2C if it is) with the authentication methods to be responded to the service provider (SP) with SAML 2.0 protocol. The authentication method set in the assertion for ‘RequestedAuthnContext’ should be as the following example SAML request: -

```xml
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                    ID="_7171b0b2-19f2-4ba2-8f94-24b5e56b7f1e"
                    IssueInstant="2014-01-30T16:18:35Z"
                    Version="2.0"
                    AssertionConsumerServiceIndex="0">
    <saml:Issuer>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"/>
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
        <saml:AuthnContext>
            <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
        </saml:AuthnContext>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

- Also, the ‘AuthnContextClassref’ of ‘unspecified’ as received by you in the SAML response implies that any authentication method that the service provider chooses can be used for authentication. Thus, the IdP responds with ‘PasswordProtectedtransport’ as the preferred choice of token issuing method and indirectly states that the preferred method authentication is not specified in the SAML request.

Please find the below link for reference on the ‘RequestedAuthnContext’ parameter: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol#requestauthncontext

Comment: Hi @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT, many thanks for your response.  Could you be more specific about how I can configure the AuthnContextClassRef value in SAML response on the B2C side?  I may have missed something but from the articles you have shared this is still not clear to me.

Re. your second point I think you may have mis-understood my question.  It is the SP that is requesting *PasswordProtectedTransport* and not the Idp responding with it.  For the avoidance of doubt the Idp is responding with *unspecified* and therefore is rejected by the SP which is wanting an exact match.

Comment: Yes, I can understand that, it might be that my statements in the answer gave you other understanding. IdP in here means Azure AD responds as unspecified because here SAML SP is requesting SAML response as 'PasswordProtectedTransport' whereas Azure AD doesn't support that, it only supports 'Password' as in RequestedAuthnContext assertion class.